# Web api c# relacionamento entre tabelas

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando fazer a relação entre duas classes "Tabelas".

Estou montando uma API pelo MVC5 EF6 no Visual Studio porem preciso que uma informação de uma classe apareça na outra.

```
public class ASSOCIADO
{

    public string ID_EMPRESA { get; set; }

    *public ICollection<EMPRESA> NM_FANTASIA_EMPRESA { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string ID_ASSOCIADO { get; set; }
    public string NM_ASSOCIADO { get; set; }
    public string NR_CPF { get; set; }
    public string DS_EMAIL { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DT_NASCIMENTO { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DT_INATIVACAO { get; set; }

    *public virtual EMPRESA NM_FANSTASIA_EMPRESA { get; set; }

}
```

Neste código acima, tenho as informações do associado e tenho o CD_EMPRESA (KEY na Classe de Empresa), os códigos com * foram algumas tentativas encontradas na internet para trazer esses valores.

Em outra Classe tenho esse código:

```
public class EMPRESA
    {
            [Key]
            public string ID_EMPRESA { get; set; }
            public string NM_FANTASIA_EMPRESA { get; set; }

    }
```

Preciso apresentar o NM_FANTASIA_EMPRESA na classe ASSOCIADO, para que de acordo com o ID_EMPRESA dele.

Comment: um associado tem 1 ou várias empresas ? se 1, usa o código de baixo, se não, o código de cima. Pode remover `public string ID_EMPRESA { get; set; }` do associado também

Comment: @RovannLinhalis ele tem apenas 1 empresa.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis fiz a alteração e buscou o valor que queria, obrigado!